# Is there a universal or general “matrix-builder” notation?

Tags: matrices, notation

If one wants to compactly construct a series, one writes $$\sum_{i=1}^w a_i=a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_w$$

If one wants to compactly construct a set, one writes $$\bigcup_{j=1}^x B_j = B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3\cup\cdots\cup B_x$$

A benefit to these notations is that they require no extra explanation except for their arguments, which can actually be defined after the “big symbol” itself.

If one wants to compactly construct a *matrix*, what “big operator” might one use to notate or stand in for

$$\boldsymbol{C}(y,z) =
\begin{pmatrix}
c(1,1) & c(1,2) & c(1,3) & \cdots & c(1,z) \\
c(2,1) & c(2,2) & c(2,3) & \cdots & c(2,z) \\
c(3,1) & c(3,2) & c(3,3) & \cdots & c(3,z) \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c(y,1) & c(y,2) & c(y,3) & \cdots & c(y,z) \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I suppose one could do something weird like defining

$$\mathop{\LARGE\mathrm{M}}_{(k,\ell)=(1,1)}^{(y,z)}c(k,\ell)$$

but I would like something more universal, perhaps involving $\prod$, $\sum$, and $\boldsymbol{I}_{y\times x}$ (the $y\times z$ identity matrix).

Comment: I think typically one just says "Consider the matrix $C$ with entries $c_{ij} = \dots$", although I have sometimes seen $[c_{ij}]_{m\times n}$.

Comment: That’s interesting. To what extent would you say it is universally applicable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen the notation $(c(k,\ell))_{k\ell}$ or maybe a variant like $(c(k,\ell))_{k=1,\ell=1}^{y,z}$ or $(c(k,\ell))_{k=1\ldots y,\ell=1\ldots z}$.  With the first, one usually specifies the dimensions in the surrounding text.

The notation is sort of an "anonymous" tensor, where contraction ends up being substitution.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by “'anonymous' tensor”? Sounds fascinating…

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Anonymous just in the sense of "no name."  For example, with respect to a basis $v^1,\dots,v^n$, one can write a vector $\sum_i(i^2)_iv^i=v^1+4v^2+9v^3+\dots+n^2v^n$, where $(i^2)_i$ is the anonymous tensor.  I could have also written $\sum_ic_iv^i$ where $c_i=i^2$, giving the object the name $c$.  It is similar to anonymous functions like $x\mapsto x^2$, where say $(x\mapsto x^2)(3)=3^2$.  I just gave a 1-tensor example, but you can have any number of indices, each either upper- or lower-indices.